# Navigating doesn't work in nativescript anymore

Tags: vue.js, navigation, nativescript

I'm developing an app in nativescript vue.
During development, the `this.$navigateTo()` function stopped working.
Because I was sure, I didn't do anything wrong, I created this [example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=DEpIEC&v=2).

It doesn't if I want to preview it on my phone, so I am starting to think it's my phone's fault.
Have I done any mistakes? Does it work on your phone?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can navigate only to a `Page`, your HelloWorld component is a Page but Next component is not. You should wrap it with `Page` element